# SharePoint 2013 Foundation - installed SP1 but CA (under servers in farm) show "no action required"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I installed SharePoint 2013 Foundation - installed SP1 but CA (under servers in farm) show "no action required". I am a bit confused here because based on my past experience should this not show "upgrade required" and then I will run psconfig?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The status of **"Action Required"** change depends on **"[Product/patch installation or server upgrade required](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/product-patch-installation-or-server-upgrade-required/)"** rule that runs **Daily**.

[image]

So in Central Administration, try to run this rule now! and check the **"Action Required"** status again.

**In the end,** you should run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard to apply the installed updates.

> For more details, please check [Product/patch installation or server upgrade required.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/product-patch-installation-or-server-upgrade-required/)

Comment: tried it but still the same.